# QML custom keyboard layouts with the same language

Tags: linux, qt, qml

I have a Qt 5.9.4 QML application working on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 using the en_GB keyboard layout.
For only one of my screens I need custom layout and I have copied the Qt keyboard layout *.qml files, rearranged and imported them.

The custom keyboard is shown on every screen, but I need it on only one.
How can this be done?

**main.cpp**

```
qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
qputenv("QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH", "/path/to/layouts");
```

**window.qml**
I'm using InputMethod just to position the keyboard inside the form.

```
InputPanel
{
   id: inputPanel
   anchors.left: parent.left
   anchors.right: parent.right
   y: active ? parent.height - inputPanel.height : parent.height
}
```

Thank you.